# Rails 200 status codes change to 302 if a request takes too long?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, activerecord

I have a rails app that fires off some code to assemble a large report on all a users data. This takes ages and needs to come off an external API (salesforce).

I have code that works on many records:

- Grabbing the data
- Formatting it correctly
- Passing it to the view and rendering as a pdf before refreshing the page with ajax.

Most requests end like this:

`Rendered record_requests/_get_digest.html.erb (2974.9ms)
 Rendered record_requests/get_digest.js.erb (2983.4ms)
 Completed 200 OK in 5957ms (Views: 2770.9ms | ActiveRecord: 222.1ms)`

Which is great!

But some of the largest records can take 6+ minutes to grab and process - at which point something different occurs:
```

`Redirected to https://[base_URL]/record_requests/5
 Completed 302 Found in 288345ms (ActiveRecord: 2.4ms)`

This is also a disaster because the redirect seems to kick off the initial request again so i get stuck in a loop...

These two requests use exactly the same code!! Why is one getting rendered and the other getting redirected? Is there a built-in rails timeouts.

Soo confused, can anyone shed any light on this?

This all works via the very excellent [Restforce](https://github.com/ejholmes/restforce) gem,the full gemfile is listed [here](http://pastebin.com/ksUqdnnV).

The controller looks like this:

`# GET /record_requests/1
  def show
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {}
      # format.json { head :ok }
      format.js
    end
  end`

`# GET /record_requests/1/get_record
  def get_digest
    @client = @record_request.client_digest
    @request_digest = @record_request.build_request_digest
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end`

Answer (score 1):

If its pretty much exactly 600s it will be a timeout.

I would guess, possible sources are:

- salesforce itself, althought I can't see a mention of a specific timeout for requests
- the client library you use to call the api, and how you handle the reponse
- the webserver you host on

Of the three, as it's rails showing the redirect - I would guess it's the second one, but without the details of the code and library you use, it's hard to say - it depends on how you handle errors in that method.

Comment: Thanks tim, i'm pretty sure that I can see the requests coming through so i'm confident the salesforce api and client library are ok... which leaves my dev server... seems likely.

How can i get a better trace on this, though, currently I have no indication of what's going on where!

Comment: If you update your question - with the library you are using to call salesforce, and perhaps the code around the request in the controller. What might be happening is that the request is timing out, and your error handling is then causing a redirect_to on fail - update - do you say you see it completing - so the logging shows it completed ok in your controller/model code?

Comment: also  - are you using anything inbetween your request servier to salesforce, like a proxy that might enforce a 600s timeout?

Comment: Not as far as I know. All rails authentication and interface is handled by [EJ Holmes' Restforce gem](https://github.com/ejholmes/restforce), here's [my gemfile](http://pastebin.com/ksUqdnnV), I think probably the bigger thing is that I'm using [c9.io](https://c9.io/) to run a remote dev environment, so I'm not privy to what's running down the stack there... is this the kind of thing that could by something lower than rails (rack? Nginx?)

Comment: You might be onto something here Tim, just spotted [this](https://github.com/ejholmes/restforce/blob/66ef4acdd0517e7b31a4105af242c1948723157f/CHANGELOG.md#104-jan-8-2013) in the restforce documentation which would seem to suggest there's a faraday timeout at 300 seconds... just tried tweaking that to longer and re-running... which see how it goes